# Remove specific strings from an Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am solving a practice problem in Practice-it and there is a question that is saying to creating an empty array inside a function and pass the array of strings as an argument into the function and to remove a specific word from it.

Here is the question: 
Write a function named removeAll that accepts an array of Strings and a single String as parameters, and returns a new array. The returned array should be equivalent to the parameter array but with all occurrences of the String parameter removed, ignoring case. The array parameter should remain unchanged as a result of the function call. For example, if an array named words contains ["foo", "bar", "baz", "Foo", "FOO"], the call of removeAll(words, "foo") should return ["bar", "baz"].

My code: I am getting undefined

```
function removeAll(words, remove){
  let arr = [];
  remove = '';
  arr = arr.filter(words => words !== remove);
}

removeAll(["foo", "bar", "baz"], "foo");
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: why are you setting remove to `''` ?

Comment: You should filter `words`, not `arr`

Comment: `function removeAll(words, remove){
  words = words.filter(word => word !== remove);
}`

Comment: You do not return anything.... and your code does not handle cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your close, but you have 2 mistakes.  Do not set remove to `''`. And filter words not `arr`

```
function removeAll(words, remove){
  return words.filter(word => word.toLowerCase() !== remove.toLowerCase());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the variables internally in the wrong way.

```js
// toLowerCase to compare lowercase strings
function removeAll(words, remove){
  return words.filter(word => 
    word.toLowerCase() !== remove.toLowerCase()
  );
}

console.log(removeAll(["foo", "bar", "baz", "FOO"], "foo"));


// Using Arrow functions
removeAllES6 = (words, remove) => 
   words.filter(word => word.toLowerCase() !== remove.toLowerCase())

console.log(removeAllES6(["foo", "bar", "baz", "FOO"], "foo"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to what is already mentioned, since you need a case insensitive comparision, use `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()`

```
function removeAll(words, remove){
  return words.filter(words => words.toUpperCase() !== remove.toUpperCase());
}

arr = removeAll(["foo", "bar", "baz"], "foO");
```